# Visual Studio 2017 Browser Link with custom url

Tags: visual-studio-2017, browser-link

I work on a few websites in different solutions that integrate with each other. To get them to work properly locally, I have to override the URLs. When I change the url from localhost:[port] to local.mydomain.com:[port], browser link no longer works. Can I assume this is a security feature and visual studio won't let me debug javascript unless I'm running as localhost?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the welcome tour to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.